# Blocking Amazon AWS servers from Rails 4 application?

Tags: security, ruby-on-rails-4, amazon-web-services, heroku, blacklist

I have a Rails 4 application running on Heroku with `exception_notification`. I was notified that an AWS server was fishing for a login page by trying to access `/wp-login.php`. Since that is not my app's login page, someone had to manually enter that URL. Tracking the IP shows an Amazon AWS server in Oregon.

There shouldn't be any reason why someone would ever access my app via an AWS server, so my initial thought is someone is trying to get into the application.

In order to avoid any potential attack, I'm thinking about blocking all Amazon AWS requests.

Is there any way to blacklist Amazon AWS servers specifically?  The only thing I can think of is checking the IP address of every request and ignoring those coming from a list I keep of Amazon, but I'm not sure if there is an official listing of Amazon IP addresses.

But checking the IP of every request against a blacklist seems inefficient. I'm aware of the `rack-attack` gem, but that is still running Ruby code to do the check, which doesn't seem very fast...

Comment: Very unlikely that someone entered that url manually.  It's extremely common to see these requests in server logs.  People write bots that crawl the web looking for poorly configure WP installs.

Comment: @sheepdog: If it's a bot, wouldn't I want to ignore those requests as well? My application is such that I don't need users to "find" it via Google/etc; they are given access to the application. My thinking is to avoid any sort of attack before it happens; I may be a bit paranoid, but would prefer to be safe than sorry :)

Comment: I don't think it's worth the effort. If you ran your access logs through elasticsearch/kibana/geoip you would probably find similar requests from all over the world.  I think you would end up playing wack-a-mole for a negligible security gain.  It's alarming when you first see it, but not actually anything to worry about.

Answer (score 0):

Blocking all AWS IPs is not a good solution. Potentially, the traffic can come from any part of the world. How are you going to block the traffic? Instead you should make your application robust.

There is an official listing of AWS IP address: [AWS IP Address Ranges](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/aws-ip-ranges.html)

If you are 100% sure that traffic originating from AWS (remember there are many AWS regions), then you can block them using IP tabled. One such solution is: [AWS Blocker](https://github.com/corbanworks/aws-blocker/blob/master/aws-blocker)

Blocking all AWS IPs is not a good solution.

Comment: Thanks for your response. My thinking was that any traffic coming from Amazon AWS would be someone trying to attack my application. Does Amazon operate like an ISP and service non-AWS traffic, such that a client on their browser using my application would appear as if it's Amazon? I was thinking about just checking the IP of each request compared to a blacklist and then ignore the request if it was within Amazon's IP range. With regards to making the app more robust, are there better alternatives? I just thought IP blocking would be the cleanest solution, but am open to better ideas.

Comment: @DanL what about *reporting the abuse to Amazon AWS?*  Are you aware of the size and scope of AWS?  As the largest cloud service provider, they are not the least bit interested in making a few dollars off of small time actors, script kiddies, and fraudsters and will shut it down if you privide them with good logs.  Blocking Amazon source addresses makes about as much sense as completely disconnecting your site from the Internet.  Yes, it's entirely possible for browser traffic to originate from AWS space, for a variety of reasons.